# Polynomial , and accumulation points of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials

Hy , I would like to have some help on the following problem .

let $p \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ and for  a positive integer $n$ , let  $u_{n}=\cos(\pi p(n))$
suppose that   the set of accumulation points of $(u_{n})$  is finite . 
Prove that : 
$p(X)-p(0) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$  .

it's feels like it is related to weyl theorem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use equidistribution results like Weyl's, Corollary 6 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/#more-3606); note rational coefficients in the polynomial can be ignored since it would suffice to show equidistribution modulo $1/q$ to contradict the finiteness of the accumulation points. But equidistribution is overkill.

We will show that if $p\in\mathbb R[X]$ satisfies $p(X)-p(0)\not\in\mathbb Q[X]$ then $p$ has infinitely many accumulation points mod $1.$

Assume by induction that this proposition is true for polynomials of smaller degree. By multiplying by a suitable integer we can assume that the top coefficient $c_n$ of $p$ is irrational.

If $p$ is linear then it is of the form $c_1n+c_0$ with $c_1$ irrational; this set is dense mod $1$ (I assume you know this), so has infinitely many accumulation points.

Otherwise, the degree of $p$ is greater than $1.$ The polynomial defined by $q(n)=p(n+1)-p(n)$ is non-constant and has the same top coefficient but smaller degree, so by the induction hypothesis must have infinitely many accumulation points mod $1.$ That implies that $p$ has infinitely many accumulation points mod $1,$ because the accumulation points of $q$ are differences of accumulation points of $p.$

Comment: thank you a lot for you help , I tried induction but , I didn't notice that the accumulation points of $q$ are differences of accumulation points of $p$  , can you elaborate please . But from your solution , correct me if I am wrong  strating from an accumation point of $p$ we can generate infinitly many , since $p(n+1)=p(n)+q(n)$ and $q$ has infinitely many , but how to prove that $p$ has at least one accumulation point ? thank you

Comment: @oty: first I should mention that all accumulation points should be mod $1$ i.e. on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z.$ This is a sequentially compact space so for any sequence there is a convergent subsequence, giving an accumulation point. So $p(n)$ has at least one accumulation point mod $1.$ And given any accumulation point $c$ of $q(n),$ so $q(n_k)\to c$ mod $1,$ we can take a subsequence $n'_k$ of $n_k$ such that $p(n'_{k})$ also converges mod $1.$ Then $p(n'_k+1)$ converges to $p(n'_k)+c$ mod $1,$ so $c$ is a difference of accumulation points of $p(n).$

Comment: thank you a lot , that's what i was thinking about :) Problem solved .